# Amount of programming needed to become a decent industrial engineer

Tags: industrial-engineering

I am interested in becoming an industrial engineer. I know the basics of Java and Python but I cannot program well. I am wondering whether it is still possible for me to become an industrial engineer.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Comment: (1) Take a 2-3 quarters of some serious programming language (beyond basics).  Programming skills hardly ever hurt anyone's career.  You don't know what path you career will have to take in 5 years.  (2) If you end up doing serious programming, you will have to scramble in order to absorb a lot of industry knowledge, which is not widely known in academia (it usually doesn't fit the school mold).  Present-day academic institutions aren't known for making industrial-grade programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Industrial engineering is not one of those professions where the engineers need to be particularly good programmers, unless you plan on developing industrial engineering software, in which case, it could be a problem.

Because IE involves optimization of industrial processes and procedures, you probably will find yourself learning how to use various computer tools to assist in these tasks, much like other engineers would learn how to use spreadsheets or CAD programs, but you would not be expected to develop these tools yourself from scratch.

Comment: Not very many people will get to start programing from scratch. Even programmers dont do that anymore. I was once asked by a CS major to setup the basic scaffolding so he could compile as he had never in his 15 years in the trade done that! And no nobody makes their own CAD, but might need to use the cad applications API to do something with a for loop such as autimatically export your scene into a FEM app so you can do a global optimization with all the parametric functions, including patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a complex question. Learning the syntax of Java or Python specifically has a decent risk of not being especially helpful at least in the sense that your next workplace may not actually use those languages. What does stand a chance of being helpful is the process of abstracting your eningeering problem into something that can be turned into code - this will challenge your understanding of the underlying eningeering principles and make you a better engineer. But to do this you need to have reached a level in programming where converting an engineering task into code is a feasible objective ( to a degree it is not necessary to succeed at this task to obtain this benefit but it is necessary to be able to attempt it seriously).
What is also useful is to learn enough of a language that you can consider the semantics ahead of the syntax - then you can effectively generalise your knowledge of programming into situations which are unrelated to the language(s) you learned which may well not be the ones you are required to code in. This is related to the other answers references to programming skills increasing CAD or spreadsheet skills.

Answer (score -1):

All higher level functions in engineering start to resemble programming jobs more and more as time goes by. Many students want to avoid hearing this, after all they did not choose computer science (CS). Do you need it?  No not really, but it can be extremely useful for many careers and valuable in general. Same could be said for most of your subjects.

Lets take the CAD as an example. CAD is asymptotically closing in on programming. Sure you can use CAD in a stupid manner but parametrical CAD design is allready a weird graphical programing language in its own right. When you start taking more advantage of it to make Design Automation and increasing your own productivity your smack middle in programing land. Not computer science mind you but programming nonetheless.

Case point analytical software like FEM and other simulation packages usually require you to be atleast somewhat programmer savy to get into those optimisation problems that currently arent being solved. You need to be able to run many simulations and touchup larger and lager sets of data. Sure using simulation data management helps but this is moving towards scripting related things all the time.

Same applies to calculations they are all moving to computers and you would certainly call the things programs. I know people tend to use spreadsheets for many of these tasks, but there is a limit to how practical a spreadsheet is in many contexts. The advice i would give you is to learn to graph in python or matlab it sidesteps many problems and mistakes you will make in excel. This also helps you understand physics better.

Other areas such as documentation, requirements are strongly moving into this direction as well. Automation is also some sort of programing branch and you should be atleast somewhat familiar with those things. Already most but the softest of soft Ph.D level works involve programming, most master levels follow soon.

You do not nessecerily have to be a stellar programer, thats what the cs majors are for. You just need to be the guy who can whip up a program to solve a problem in the domain of your speciality, because CS graduates lack this. This is also something unversities in general approach badly so taking more courses in computer sciece wont help you much. But do take a algorithms 101 course, that is useful if you ever need to build a machine to separate or sort things and teaches basics of what Compuer Science as opposed to programming is really about.